# view is null in fragment onresume

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, onresume

As I need to call a fragment on resume I created an Interface for fragment with two method:

```
public interface FragmentLifecycle {
    public void onResumeFragment();
}
```

all of my fragments implements this interface.

I use this piece of code to replace my **TutorialFragment** with main fragment initially:

```
Fragment fragment = new TutorialFragment();
fragment.setArguments( selectedCat );
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.category_fragment,fragment );
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack( null );
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

when on my main fragment I call **onResumeFragment** method of **TutorialFragment**:

```
FragmentLifecycle tutorial_fragment= new TutorialFragment();
tutorial_fragment.onResumeFragment();
```

I need view of the fragment for my function to show my data but I get null when I want to use view or call **getview()**:

```
@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    Log.e( Tag," view in onResumeFragment "+getView() );
}
```

how can I access view of my fragment when my fragment called from another fragment?

Answer (score 4):

When you're calling the method `onResumeFragment()` directly after creating the Fragment with:

```
FragmentLifecycle tutorial_fragment= new TutorialFragment();
tutorial_fragment.onResumeFragment();
```

You won't get any View in the method because the view isn't attached to the fragment yet and Fragment is not created yet. Creating the Fragment is **asynchronous** process, so you need to wait until the fragment is created.

You need to create a callback to tell the activity that the fragment is created.

Comment: please elaborate your answer, could you give me an example? or any documentation? I can tell activity that view is created but how can I manipulate fragment view from activity? I need to repopulate RecyclerView inside fragment with new data so I choose to run onResumeFragment.